# cmd use input as variable

Tags: variables, input, cmd, prompt

am trying to write a batch file that will take user input and use it to call from a list of stored variables.

I have already figured out how to do this using IF statements, but I feel like there must be a cleaner way!

What am looking for is something like this:

```
Set A=1
SET P%A%= Hello
```

*This works and can be echoed:

```
ECHO %P1%
```

*Output: Hello

```
Set /P Prompt Input Selection:
Prompt=1
SET Var=%Prompt%

ECHO %P(!var!)%
```

*Ideally this would be the same as:

```
ECHO %P1%
```

Or whatever the prompt value is for the desired value of %a% but I cannot get this part to work

Answer (score 0):

`Prompt=1` should be `set Prompt=1`

`ECHO %P(!var!)%` should be `echo !p%x%!` (with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` of course)